# JQgrid save and recover object from column

Tags: object, jqgrid, hidden

It is posible to save a complex objet into a column and to recover it after.

This is an example:
Json:

```
[{"datamain":"mydata",
       "address":{"data1":15,"data2":0.0,"data3":"1000"}}
}]
```

Jqgrid:

```
jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid({  
        datatype: "local",
        loadtext:"Loading...",
        colNames:['Name',
                  'obaddress'],
        colModel:[
        {name:'datamain',index:'datamain', width:200,editable: true,edittype:'text'},
        {name:'address',index:'address', width:30, editable: false,hidden : true,edittype:'text'}
                ],
        cellsubmit: "clientArray",  
        pager:"#pager"
    });
```

If I try to access addres:

```
 var rowData = $("#rowed5").getRowData(rowid);
var myaddress= rowData['address'];
```

Then I get '[object Object]' but it is a string!!! I can not do: `myaddress.data1`

Any recommendation???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem you can do the following:

```js
var rowData = $("#rowed5").jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);
alert("data3=" + rowData.address.data3);
```

By the way to save the `address` part you don't need to create hidden column `"address"`. So *you don't create any hidden column in the table to hold any row specific custom data*. You should just fill the data like you do as typically: using `data` option of jqGrid:

```js
var mydata = [
    {
        id: "10",
        "datamain": "mydata",
        "address": {"data1": 15, "data2": 0.0, "data3": "1000"}
    },
    {
        id: "20",
        "datamain": "mydata2",
        "address": {"data1": 18, "data2": 0.1, "data3": "3000"}
    }
];

$("#rowed5").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: mydata,
    colNames: ['Name'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'datamain', width: 300, editable: true}
    ],
    height: "auto",
    ...
});
```

In the case **all the data** will be saved in the internal `data` parameter of jqGrid. You can use `$("#rowed5").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` to return all the data or use  `$("#rowed5").jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid)` to return the data of the specified row only.

[The small demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/complexlocaldata.htm) demonstrate the approach live. The data are displayed one row per page. So you can go to the next page and modify the data using cell editing. After saving the "address" information from the current cell will be displayed.

Comment: I just resolved the problem. The main proble was that I have to load data on this way:       jQuery("#rowed5")
      .jqGrid('setGridParam',
          { 
              datatype: 'local',
              data:mydata
          })
      .trigger("reloadGrid");

Comment: Good call on "getLocalRow" method. This returned the object as apposed to "getRowData" which returned the string. Thanks.

Comment: @styfle: You are welcome! Additional advantage of `getLocalRow` and internal `data` and `_index` is the following: if `mydata` contains additional properties there will be save in exactly the same form as input data. So one need no hidden columns and one can even save complex objects associated with rows. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13241406/315935) and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13779589/315935) where nested subgrid information will be hold in `data` and be accessed using `getLocalRow`.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the problem. The main problem was that I have to load data on this way:

```
        jQuery("#rowed5")
        .jqGrid('setGridParam',
            { 
                datatype: 'local',
                data:mydata
            })
        .trigger("reloadGrid");
```

You don't have to do this:

```
       jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid("clearGridData", true);
        for(var i=0;i < data.item.length;i++){
            jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid('addRowData',i,data.item[i]);
        }
```