# JQuery Grid-SubGrid for Parent-Child relation

Tags: json, jquery, jqgrid

I need some idea, about how to implement a subgrid in the following sceaniro.

The following is the json data that I want to display in the JQuery Grid and Subgrid.
Basically I am getting an object called "Contact" that has a collection called "actionSet".

```
{
 "total" : "10",
 "page" : "1",
 "records" : "78",
 "rows" : [ {
   "comment" : null,
   "givenName" : "Contact A",
   "familyName" : "A",
   "actionSet" : [ {
       "actionID" : 1,
       "actionDueDate" : "2012-12-08",
       "actionNote" : "Action 1"
       }, {
       "actionID" : 2,
       "actionDueDate" : "2012-12-08",
       "actionNote" : "Action 2"
  } ]
 }    ...]

}
```

I want eache Grid row to display the "Contact" and the subgris associated with the grid should display "actionSet" collection.

When a particular row in the Grid is selected, I do not want to make a server call to get the associated actions, as they are allready present in the "actionSet".

I have got the Grid working, displaying the "Contacts" nicely, but I get confused while implement the subgrid, as how to get the data for it, as its allready available in json.

```
jq(function() {
 jq("#grid").jqGrid({
 url:'/smallworks/project/getall.do',
 datatype: 'json',
 mtype: 'GET',
   colNames:['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name'],
   colModel:[
     {name:'id',index:'id', width:55,editable:false,editoptions:   {readonly:true,size:10},hidden:true},
   {name:'givenName',index:'givenName', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
   {name:'familyName',index:'familyName', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}}
  ],
  postData: {
  },
  rowNum:20,
  rowList:[20,40,60],
  height: 200,
  autowidth: true,
  rownumbers: true,
  pager: '#pager',
  sortname: 'id',
  viewrecords: true,
  sortorder: "asc",
  caption:"Contacts",
  emptyrecords: "Empty records",
  loadonce: false,
  loadComplete: function() {
  },
```

Is this achievable?
Do I need to parse JSON data specially for the subgrid?
How can this be achieved?

Comment: I think I can suggest you some way to solve the problem, but one thing seems strange for me: the JSON data which you post contain no `id` data for every row. Moreover I don't understand the value of `id` column in the grid. Do you plan to show the `id` for the user or it will be used only for internal purpose? In the last case you can just remove `id` column and the `sortname: 'id'` parameter. The `id` property from the JSON input will be used to set **`id` attribute of `<tr>` elements** which represent rows of the grid (the HTML table).

Comment: Hi Oleg, I will remove the id from the column, which makes sense, as it should for internal purpose, but my question regarding the subgrid still remains, and what what I am really seeking ideas for. I have read your answers to some other post and they are all great. I hope to get some direction from you on this one.

Comment: I will add `id` properties to every element of `rows` array and post the answer (later) which correspond the modified data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you save information from `actionSet` in an object which you can easy access later. For example you can use `userData` parameter and fill the `userdata` part of JSON data inside of `beforeProcessing`. The create subgrid you can follow [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10178440/315935) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13241406/315935).

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Adofo.htm) demonstrate the implementation approach:

[image]

It uses the following code

```js
var mainGridPrefix = "s_";

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: "Adofo.json",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ["First Name", "Last Name"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "givenName" },
        { name: "familyName" }
    ],
    cmTemplate: {width: 100, editable: true, editrules: {required: true},
        editoptions: {size: 10}},
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20, 40, 60],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    caption: "Contacts",
    rownumbers: true,
    autoencode: true,
    height: "100%",
    idPrefix: mainGridPrefix,
    subGrid: true,
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
    beforeProcessing: function (data) {
        var rows = data.rows, l = rows.length, i, item, subgrids = {};
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            item = rows[i];
            if (item.actionSet) {
                subgrids[item.id] = item.actionSet;
            }
        }
        data.userdata = subgrids;
    },
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
        var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
            pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, rowId),
            subgrids = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData");

        $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
        $subgrid.jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: subgrids[pureRowId],
            colNames: ["Due Date", "Note"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "actionDueDate", formatter: "date", sorttype: "date" },
                { name: "actionNote" }
            ],
            sortname: "actionDueDate",
            height: "100%",
            rowNum: 10000,
            autoencode: true,
            autowidth: true,
            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "actionID" },
            gridview: true,
            idPrefix: rowId + "_"
        });
    }
});
```

**UPDATED**: The JSON data used in the demo one can see below. I added `id` property which is required for jqGrid. I used `actionID` as the `id` of the subgrids:

```json
{
    "total": "10",
    "page": "1",
    "records": "78",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "comment": null,
            "givenName": "Contact A",
            "familyName": "A",
            "actionSet": [
                {
                    "actionID": 1,
                    "actionDueDate": "2012-12-08",
                    "actionNote": "Action 1"
                },
                {
                    "actionID": 2,
                    "actionDueDate": "2012-12-09",
                    "actionNote": "Action 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "comment": null,
            "givenName": "Contact B",
            "familyName": "B",
            "actionSet": [
                {
                    "actionID": 3,
                    "actionDueDate": "2012-12-11",
                    "actionNote": "Action 3"
                },
                {
                    "actionID": 4,
                    "actionDueDate": "2012-12-10",
                    "actionNote": "Action 4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thank you for the reply. I have tried it and subgrid is not displaying properly.
May I please have a look at the data you are using.
When I was tring to debug by putting in the alerts I discovered that in the function "beforeProcessing", "item.id" is undefined.
May be its the data differnece between your code and mine. I have attached the image above.

Comment: @Adofo: I wrote you before (see my comments to your question) about the requirement to include `id` property. I did this in the demo which I used. See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Adofo.json).

Comment: Thanx Oleg, my JSON is broken, I will fix it and try again, I will keep you posted. I am sure, ones the JSON is fine it will work.

Comment: @Adofo: You should not edit *my* answer. Instead of that you can append the text of *your question* with words like "**UPDATED**" and any additional information. You should post an comment to other question to inform answers about the changes in your question. It's standard way on the stackoverflow.

Comment: @Adofo: The JSON data which you try to post still don't contains `id` properties.

Comment: Thanx for letting know, how to append, by using "UPDATE", its all good :)