# Storing a json array in a hidden column of a jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I have a `jqgrid` set up to be fed from a `JSON` response from a remote URL. One of the fields I am sending back in my `JSON` is an array of values. I am attempting to store this array in a hidden column so that it will be accessible when an element in the grid is selected, but `jqgrid`is converting my array into the string `[object Object]`.

Is there a way to convince `jqgrid` to leave arrays intact so that they can be accessed with `getRowData` or do you have to encode arrays into strings on the server and then decode them on the client?

Answer (score 2):

Hidden column is just a column which has CSS style `display: none`. You can't place object on HTML page inside of `<td>...</td>`. So the object will be converted to string automatically by calling `toString` method.

What you really need is saving of objects (array for example) **somewhere**. When the user selects later a row of grid the callback `onSelectRow` are called. The callback has rowid as a parameter. So the best will be to save your custom information as dictionary (object) by rowids.

One of the option will be sending additional information not inside of `rows` part of the server response, but inside of `userdata` instead. For example you try to send currently the data in the following format

```js
{
    "page": 1
    "total": 7
    "records": 123
    "rows": [
        {"id": 10, "cell": ["cell11", "cell12", "cell13", [1, 2, 3]]}
        {"id": 20, "cell": ["cell11", "cell12", "cell13", [4, 5, 6]]},
        ...
        {"id": 90, "cell": ["cell11", "cell12", "cell13", [9, 8, 7]]}
    ]
}
```

You can modify the server response to

```js
{
    "page": 1
    "total": 7
    "records": 123
    "rows": [
        {"id": 10, "cell": ["cell11", "cell12", "cell13", [1, 2, 3]]}
        {"id": 20, "cell": ["cell11", "cell12", "cell13", [4, 5, 6]]},
        ...
        {"id": 90, "cell": ["cell11", "cell12", "cell13", [9, 8, 7]]}
    ],
    "userdata": {
        "10": [1, 2, 3],
        "20": [4, 5, 6],
        ...
        "90": [9, 8, 7]
    }
}
```

In the case the `userdata` part will be automatically saved by jqGrid inside of internal parameter `userData` (be carefull with usage of case in "userdata" in JSON data and `"userData"` as parameter).

Now you will be able to get your custom data inside any callback in the following way:

```js
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    var custom = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData");

    // custom[rowid] is the data from userdata like [4, 5, 6]
}
```

If you can't modify the server response you can move your custom data to `userdata` part inside of `beforeProcessing` callback. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935) for an example of such code.