# Have jqGrid display raw json in a column

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have a use case where I would like to have jqGrid display some raw JSON for a particular column. I have the following JSON being sent from the server:

```
{"items":[
    {
        "code":"ABC123",
        "description":"",
        "custom_data":{"items":[
            {"prop1":"val1","prop2":"val2"},
            {"prop1":"val3","prop2":"val4"}
        ]}
    },
    {"code":"ABC124","description":"","custom_data":[]},
    ...,
]}
```

and a jqGrid configuration like so:

```
{
url:'/api/somewhere',
datatype: "json",
jsonReader : {
    root:"items",
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "code"
},
colNames:['Code',
          'Description',
          'Data',],
colModel:[
    {   
            name:'code', index:'code', width:100, hidden:false, 
        edittype:'text', 
        editable: true, 
        editrules:{required:true, edithidden:true}, 
        editoptions: {readonly:false}
    },
    {   
            name:'description', 
            index:'description', 
            width:250, 
            editable:true, 
            edittype:'text', 
            editrules:{required:true} 
        },
    {
    name:'custom_data',
    index:'custom_data', 
    width:100, 
    hidden:true, 
    sortable:false, 
    editable:true, 
    edittype:'text', 
    editrules:{required:false, edithidden:true}
    },
],
    ...,
```

The grid displays OK, but the custom_data column is displayed as [object Object]. What I need is for it to display the raw JSON string I have tried calling JSON.stringify on the custom_data object for each row object using the loadComplete event, but that didn't work. I need to do some data manipulation after the GET anyway, as I want to delete null values from the custom_data object.

My users are comfortable reading and editing raw JSON, so I also need the add/edit form to accept raw JSON which will then get POSTed.

I'm not sure if I'm simply using the wrong event to convert the object back to a string, or if there is something else going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is usage of custom formatter for `"custom_data"` column

```
formatter: function (cellValue, options, rawData) {
    return cellValue.items ? JSON.stringify(cellValue.items) : "";
}
```

I changed in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/crazystick.htm) `hidden` property for `"custom_data"` column to `true` to see the data

[image]

Additionally you can consider to use `userdata` instead of hidden column to save additional custom data. I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935) additionally which shows not only how to use `userdata`, but additionally how to show additional data in form subgrid.

Comment: Thanks. Works great. I'm also stripping out my null properties in the formatter too, since modifying it in loadComplete didn't work. I'll look into userdata, I haven't come across that before, and I have a lot of hidden columns in my app!

Comment: @crazystick: You are welcome! Saving of data inside some JavaScript variable or inside of `userdata` is more effective as saving it on the HTML page as DOM elements. So it's better don't use hidden columns.