# JQGrid with xmlstring datatype, master detail, dynamic filter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, contains, xmlreader, master-detail

***UPDATED:***

Resolved, with an xmlreader like this:

```
{
id : "rowid",
repeatitems : false,
root : "response>claims>claim>units",
row : "unit:has('claimId:contains('6002950')'):has('unitId:contains('6003606')')"
}
```

As it turns out, the solution was to move the dynamic filter to the xmlreader.row level and realize that an "AND" condition for the ":has" filter chain means NO separators, as opposed to the comma, which means "OR".

So, for all of you out there who need to do something similar:

**YES**, you can switch an "xml", ajax-server-bound grid, to an "xmlstring", local bound grid, by keeping the same xml schema for the data, the same column model for the grid, and just changing the xmlreader to apply filtering locally, equivalent to the filter normally sent to the server.

The typical scenario for needing something like this is pointing the same UI to two different, data equivalent web services, but with different speed behavior. Fast web services can be called by an "xml" ajax bound grid, with server filters that limit the returned xml. Slow web services can be called outside of the grid which is later pointed to and "xmlstring" cached by the client. Data filters, in the later scenario, become client xmlreader dynamic filters applied to the xmlreader.row level.

***INITIAL QUESTION:***

My scenario is this:

- Two jqgrids, one master, one detail;
- Initially fed from fast web service ajax call, datatype xml, with xmlreader like this for the detail grid

`id : "rowid",

repeatitems : false,

root : "response>claims>claim>units",

row : "unit"`

- Switch the same grids to "disconnected" mode, data type xmlstring (basically, client stored xmlstring variable received from web service that takes too long to do multiple ajax calls);
- When master grid row is clicked, I build dynamically a filter to filter down the detail grid;
- Both grids are fed now, in "disconnected xmlstring" mode, from copies of the client stored xmlstring javascript variable;

From my prior experience with subgrids, I know you can filter the xmlstring grids by applying a selector to the xmlreader root section. So, I attempted first the following dynamic xmlreader (complete xmlstring data sample at the bottom):

```
id : "rowid",
repeatitems : false,
root : "response>claims>claim>units:has('claimId:contains('6002950'),unitId:contains('6003434')')",
row : "unit"
```

This didn't work, both rows came back and shown in the detail grid. 
At this point I looked back at my subgrid example, and saw that there I was going one level deeper with the filter. So I tried a deeper root filter:

```
id : "rowid",
repeatitems : false,
root : "response>claims>claim>units>unit:has('claimId:contains('6002950'),unitId:contains('6003434')')",
row : "unit"
```

This didn't work, either. First, the :has filter seems to not work even if I went deeper. Something must be wrong with this chained :contains filter. Moreso, now the xmlreader row section didn't make sense anymore to be "unit".

At this point, I had spent too much time with the xmlreader selector, and I was thinking to try removing the xml nodes that don't match the filter and leave the xmlreader filterless.
Tried a negative match filter on the selector I was trying in the root, by applying :not() to it.

`$(StringtoXML(dataStr)).find("response>claims>claim>units>unit:not(:has('claimId:contains('6002950'),unitId:contains('6003434')'))").remove()`

That doesn't work either, or I don't do it right (xml manipulation with jquery should be easy, I know).

If it helps anyone, in all my tests, I saw the grid reacting based on parsing of the xml data equivalent with this call (where dataStr is my locally stored xmlstring variable):

```
$(StringtoXML(dataStr)).find(xmlReader.root).children(xmlReader.row)
```

Sample xmlstring data:

```
<response>
    <claims>
        <claim>
            <sourceSystemCd>blah</sourceSystemCd>
            <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
            <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
            <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
            <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
            <appointmentDateTime/>
            <appointmentDesc/>
            <appointmentUser/>
            <assignmentDateTime/>
            <assignmentDesc/>
            <assignmentUser/>
            <actions/>
            <adjusters/>
            <claimId>6002950</claimId>
            <claimNum>141200002512</claimNum>
            <injuryInd/>
            <claimTypeCd>AUTO</claimTypeCd>
            <lossTmUnkInd/>
            <keyedDt></keyedDt>
            <towClaimInd/>
            <rptOnlyInd/>
            <priorClaimCnt/>
            <othPropDmgInd/>
            <polFireAtSceneInd/>
            <witnessInd/>
            <lossTypeLiabilityCd>02</lossTypeLiabilityCd>
            <insInjAsPedInd/>
            <insInjAsPasInd/>
            <policyFireDeptName/>
            <policyFireCaseNumber/>
            <anyConcernsTxt/>
            <claimTypeDesc/>
            <dwnTmRptDesc/>
            <lossTypeLiabilityDesc/>
            <lossLocAddrLn1Txt>shanendoah</lossLocAddrLn1Txt>
            <lossLocAddrLn2Txt/>
            <lossLocCityName/>
            <lossLocCountryCode>usa</lossLocCountryCode>
            <lossLocInsRsdncInd/>
            <lossLocZipCd/>
            <lossLocStateCd/>
            <lossLocSubdName/>
            <companyCd>03</companyCd>
            <lossTmstmp>2013-03-22 00:00:00.000</lossTmstmp>
            <lossTypeDesc/>
            <lossLocationDescription/>
            <claimparties>
                <claimparty>
                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                    <unitId>0</unitId>
                    <parties>
                        <party>
                            <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                            <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                            <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                            <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                            <recordId>6006003</recordId>
                            <objectId/>
                            <partyTypeCd>PRINMINS</partyTypeCd>
                            <partyId>6003211</partyId>
                            <primary>false</primary>
                            <partyFirstName>blah</partyFirstName>
                            <partyMiddleName>blah</partyMiddleName>
                            <partyLastName>blah</partyLastName>
                            <partyFullName>blah</partyFullName>
                            <addresses>
                                <address>
                                    <addressTypeCd>phy_addr</addressTypeCd>
                                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                                    <partyAddrCityName>BATH</partyAddrCityName>
                                    <partyAddrLn1Txt>4 Maple Lane</partyAddrLn1Txt>
                                    <partyAddrLn2Txt/>
                                    <partyAddrStCd>NH</partyAddrStCd>
                                    <partyAddrSubdName/>
                                    <partyAddrZipCd>03740</partyAddrZipCd>
                                    <partyId/>
                                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                                </address>
                            </addresses>
                            <contacts>
                                <contact>
                                    <contactId>6002660</contactId>
                                    <contactTxt>9999472127</contactTxt>
                                    <contactTypeCd>hm_phn</contactTypeCd>
                                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                                    <isTxtMsgEnabledInd/>
                                    <partyId/>
                                    <preferContactTypeInd/>
                                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                                </contact>
                            </contacts>
                            <partyDetail>
                                <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                                <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                                <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                                <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                                <injuryInd/>
                            </partyDetail>
                            <partyInjury>
                                <attorneyId/>
                                <injuryDesc/>
                                <injurySeverityCd>min</injurySeverityCd>
                                <injuryTypeCd>01</injuryTypeCd>
                                <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                                <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                                <medCareTxt/>
                                <partyId/>
                                <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                                <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                                <medcaretypes>
                                    <medcaretype>
                                        <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                                        <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                                        <medCareTypeCd>OTHER</medCareTypeCd>
                                        <partyId/>
                                        <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                                        <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                                    </medcaretype>
                                </medcaretypes>
                            </partyInjury>
                        </party>
                    </parties>
                </claimparty>
            </claimparties>
            <policy>
                <cededInd/>
                <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                <cmpyLobId>2</cmpyLobId>
                <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                <jurId>41</jurId>
                <lobCd>PA</lobCd>
                <maipInd/>
                <nsfInd/>
                <polEffDt>2012-06-14 00:00:00.000</polEffDt>
                <polExpDt>2013-06-14 00:00:00.000</polExpDt>
                <polOrigDt></polOrigDt>
                <polSubdName/>
                <policyNumber>asdasd</policyNumber>
                <policySymbol/>
                <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                <unverifiedInd>N</unverifiedInd>
                <polAddrLn1Txt>4 Mapls dfs</polAddrLn1Txt>
                <polAddrLn2Txt/>
                <polCityName>BATH</polCityName>
                <polStCd>NH</polStCd>
                <polZipCd>03740</polZipCd>
            </policy>
            <units>
                <unit>
                    <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                    <roleCategory/>
                    <sourceSystemCd>asdasd</sourceSystemCd>
                    <unitCategory>veh</unitCategory>
                    <unitDataType>veh</unitDataType>
                    <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                    <unitSubType>sch</unitSubType>
                    <unitType>veh</unitType>
                    <unitVehicle>
                        <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                        <hvyEqpmntInd/>
                        <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                        <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                        <motorcycleInd/>
                        <othInsCoName/>
                        <othPolNbr/>
                        <otherDamageDesc/>
                        <recVehInd/>
                        <totalLossPoints/>
                        <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                        <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                        <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                        <vehEstRepairInd/>
                        <vehUnoccupiedInd/>
                        <vehMakeTxt>VOLKSWAGEN</vehMakeTxt>
                        <vehModelTxt>PASSAT 2.0T WAGON VALUE</vehModelTxt>
                        <vehYearTxt>2007</vehYearTxt>
                        <vinTxt>asdasd</vinTxt>
                        <licPlateTxt/>
                        <version>0</version>
                        <recordId>6003434</recordId>
                        <estimateAmt/>
                        <estimateInd/>
                        <totalLossInd>N</totalLossInd>
                        <vehDrivableInd>N</vehDrivableInd>
                        <licPlateStateCd/>
                        <vehColorTxt/>
                        <vehLocDesc>insd pob</vehLocDesc>
                        <vehLocAddrLn1Txt>695 atlantic ave</vehLocAddrLn1Txt>
                        <vehLocCityName>boston</vehLocCityName>
                        <vehLocSubdName/>
                        <vehLocStateCd/>
                        <vehLocZipCd>02101</vehLocZipCd>
                        <vehLocContactTxt/>
                        <vehLocPhone/>
                        <vehLocAddrLn2Txt/>
                        <vehLocFormattedAddr/>
                        <vehLocLat/>
                        <vehLocLong/>
                        <vehLocPrecision/>
                    </unitVehicle>
                    <damages>
                        <damage>
                            <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                            <damageCd>ALLOTHER</damageCd>
                            <damageDesc/>
                            <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                            <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                            <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                            <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                            <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                        </damage>
                    </damages>
                    <displayUnitTypeCd>veh</displayUnitTypeCd>
                    <policyUnitTypeCd>veh</policyUnitTypeCd>
                    <coverages>
                        <coverage>
                            <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                            <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                            <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                            <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                            <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                            <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                            <coverageCd>COLL</coverageCd>
                            <covCd>collsn</covCd>
                            <coverageId>6013152</coverageId>
                            <coverageId>6013152</coverageId>
                            <deductibleTypeCd>ded</deductibleTypeCd>
                            <deductibleAmt>500.00</deductibleAmt>
                            <coverageDetails>
                                <coverageDetail>
                                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                                    <coverageCd>COLL</coverageCd>
                                    <covCd>collsn</covCd>
                                    <covDtlTypCd>ded</covDtlTypCd>
                                    <covDtlAmt>500.00</covDtlAmt>
                                    <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                                    <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                                </coverageDetail>
                            </coverageDetails>
                        </coverage>
                        <coverage>
                            <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                            <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                            <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                            <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                            <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                            <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                            <coverageCd>COMP</coverageCd>
                            <covCd>comp</covCd>
                            <coverageId>6013153</coverageId>
                            <coverageId>6013153</coverageId>
                            <deductibleTypeCd>ded</deductibleTypeCd>
                            <deductibleAmt>500.00</deductibleAmt>
                            <deductibleTypeCd>full_glass</deductibleTypeCd>
                            <deductibleAmt>0.00</deductibleAmt>
                            <coverageDetails>
                                <coverageDetail>
                                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                                    <coverageCd>COMP</coverageCd>
                                    <covCd>comp</covCd>
                                    <covDtlTypCd>ded</covDtlTypCd>
                                    <covDtlAmt>500.00</covDtlAmt>
                                    <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                                    <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                                </coverageDetail>
                                <coverageDetail>
                                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                                    <coverageCd>COMP</coverageCd>
                                    <covCd>comp</covCd>
                                    <covDtlTypCd>full_glass</covDtlTypCd>
                                    <covDtlAmt>0.00</covDtlAmt>
                                    <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                                    <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                                </coverageDetail>
                            </coverageDetails>
                        </coverage>
                        <coverage>
                            <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                            <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                            <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                            <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                            <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                            <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                            <coverageCd>NA</coverageCd>
                            <covCd>csl</covCd>
                            <coverageId>6013149</coverageId>
                            <limitTypeCd>each_occr</limitTypeCd>
                            <limitAmt>500000.00</limitAmt>
                            <coverageId>6013149</coverageId>
                            <coverageDetails>
                                <coverageDetail>
                                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                                    <coverageCd>NA</coverageCd>
                                    <covCd>csl</covCd>
                                    <covDtlTypCd>each_occr</covDtlTypCd>
                                    <covDtlAmt>500000.00</covDtlAmt>
                                    <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                                    <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                                </coverageDetail>
                            </coverageDetails>
                        </coverage>
                        <coverage>
                            <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                            <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                            <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                            <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                            <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                            <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                            <coverageCd>PIP</coverageCd>
                            <covCd>mp</covCd>
                            <coverageId>6013151</coverageId>
                            <limitTypeCd>each_pers</limitTypeCd>
                            <limitAmt>5000.00</limitAmt>
                            <coverageId>6013151</coverageId>
                            <coverageDetails>
                                <coverageDetail>
                                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                                    <coverageCd>PIP</coverageCd>
                                    <covCd>mp</covCd>
                                    <covDtlTypCd>each_pers</covDtlTypCd>
                                    <covDtlAmt>5000.00</covDtlAmt>
                                    <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                                    <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                                </coverageDetail>
                            </coverageDetails>
                        </coverage>
                        <coverage>
                            <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                            <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                            <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                            <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                            <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                            <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                            <coverageCd>TOWING</coverageCd>
                            <covCd>tow_lab</covCd>
                            <coverageId>6013154</coverageId>
                            <limitTypeCd>each_occr</limitTypeCd>
                            <limitAmt>75.00</limitAmt>
                            <coverageId>6013154</coverageId>
                            <coverageDetails>
                                <coverageDetail>
                                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                                    <coverageCd>TOWING</coverageCd>
                                    <covCd>tow_lab</covCd>
                                    <covDtlTypCd>each_occr</covDtlTypCd>
                                    <covDtlAmt>75.00</covDtlAmt>
                                    <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                                    <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                                </coverageDetail>
                            </coverageDetails>
                        </coverage>
                        <coverage>
                            <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                            <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                            <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                            <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                            <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                            <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                            <coverageCd>UMPD</coverageCd>
                            <covCd>un_und_motor</covCd>
                            <coverageId>6013150</coverageId>
                            <limitTypeCd>each_occr</limitTypeCd>
                            <limitAmt>500000.00</limitAmt>
                            <coverageId>6013150</coverageId>
                            <coverageDetails>
                                <coverageDetail>
                                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                                    <coverageCd>UMPD</coverageCd>
                                    <covCd>un_und_motor</covCd>
                                    <covDtlTypCd>each_occr</covDtlTypCd>
                                    <covDtlAmt>500000.00</covDtlAmt>
                                    <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                                    <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                                </coverageDetail>
                            </coverageDetails>
                        </coverage>
                    </coverages>
                    <rowid>6002950_6003434</rowid>
                </unit>
                <unit>
                    <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                    <roleCategory/>
                    <sourceSystemCd>asasd</sourceSystemCd>
                    <unitCategory>prop</unitCategory>
                    <unitDataType>veh</unitDataType>
                    <unitId>6003606</unitId>
                    <unitSubType>thrd</unitSubType>
                    <unitType>thrd_veh</unitType>
                    <unitVehicle>
                        <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                        <hvyEqpmntInd/>
                        <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                        <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                        <motorcycleInd/>
                        <othInsCoName/>
                        <othPolNbr/>
                        <otherDamageDesc/>
                        <recVehInd/>
                        <totalLossPoints/>
                        <unitId>6003606</unitId>
                        <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                        <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                        <vehEstRepairInd/>
                        <vehUnoccupiedInd/>
                        <vehMakeTxt>ford</vehMakeTxt>
                        <vehModelTxt>focus</vehModelTxt>
                        <vehYearTxt>2000</vehYearTxt>
                        <vinTxt>434wrewrweu9wepu</vinTxt>
                        <licPlateTxt/>
                        <version>0</version>
                        <recordId>6003606</recordId>
                        <estimateAmt/>
                        <estimateInd/>
                        <totalLossInd>N</totalLossInd>
                        <vehDrivableInd>N</vehDrivableInd>
                        <licPlateStateCd/>
                        <vehColorTxt/>
                        <vehLocDesc/>
                        <vehLocAddrLn1Txt/>
                        <vehLocCityName/>
                        <vehLocSubdName/>
                        <vehLocStateCd/>
                        <vehLocZipCd/>
                        <vehLocContactTxt/>
                        <vehLocPhone/>
                        <vehLocAddrLn2Txt/>
                        <vehLocFormattedAddr/>
                        <vehLocLat/>
                        <vehLocLong/>
                        <vehLocPrecision/>
                    </unitVehicle>
                    <damages>
                        <damage>
                            <claimId>6002950</claimId>
                            <damageCd>ALLOTHER</damageCd>
                            <damageDesc/>
                            <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                            <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                            <unitId>6003606</unitId>
                            <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                            <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                        </damage>
                    </damages>
                    <displayUnitTypeCd>thrd_veh</displayUnitTypeCd>
                    <policyUnitTypeCd>veh</policyUnitTypeCd>
                    <rowid>6002950_6003606</rowid>
                </unit>
            </units>
            <unitassignments>
                <unitassignment>
                    <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                    <reserveAmt>1800.00</reserveAmt>
                    <reserveCovCd>collsn</reserveCovCd>
                    <reserveLssTypCd>collsn</reserveLssTypCd>
                    <coverageCd>COLL</coverageCd>
                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                    <functionalRoleCode>ADJ</functionalRoleCode>
                    <adjGroupCd>ADJ</adjGroupCd>
                    <ruleGroupCd>ADJ</ruleGroupCd>
                    <claimId/>
                    <dispatchInd>Y</dispatchInd>
                    <sourceSystemCd>STREAM</sourceSystemCd>
                    <unitAsgnmntId/>
                    <adjStrmUserId>320</adjStrmUserId>
                    <unitassignmentadjusters/>
                    <primaryInd>Y</primaryInd>
                    <firstName>asdasd</firstName>
                    <lastName>asdasd</lastName>
                    <userPhoneNumber>asdasd</userPhoneNumber>
                    <userEmail>asdas@asda.com</userEmail>
                    <companyOrgUnitId>3000165</companyOrgUnitId>
                    <userTitle>Claims Representative</userTitle>
                    <dedIstrCd/>
                    <payStatusCd/>
                </unitassignment>
                <unitassignment>
                    <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                    <reserveAmt>1200.00</reserveAmt>
                    <reserveCovCd>comp</reserveCovCd>
                    <reserveLssTypCd>vand</reserveLssTypCd>
                    <coverageCd>COMP</coverageCd>
                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                    <functionalRoleCode>ADJ</functionalRoleCode>
                    <adjGroupCd>ADJ</adjGroupCd>
                    <ruleGroupCd>ADJ</ruleGroupCd>
                    <claimId/>
                    <dispatchInd>Y</dispatchInd>
                    <sourceSystemCd>asasd</sourceSystemCd>
                    <unitAsgnmntId/>
                    <adjStrmUserId>320</adjStrmUserId>
                    <unitassignmentadjusters/>
                    <primaryInd>Y</primaryInd>
                    <firstName>asd</firstName>
                    <lastName>asdasd</lastName>
                    <userPhoneNumber>asdasdas</userPhoneNumber>
                    <userEmail>asdasd@asdasd.com</userEmail>
                    <companyOrgUnitId>3000165</companyOrgUnitId>
                    <userTitle>Claims Representative</userTitle>
                    <dedIstrCd/>
                    <payStatusCd/>
                </unitassignment>
                <unitassignment>
                    <unitId>6003434</unitId>
                    <reserveAmt>1200.00</reserveAmt>
                    <reserveCovCd>comp</reserveCovCd>
                    <reserveLssTypCd>allothr</reserveLssTypCd>
                    <coverageCd>COMP</coverageCd>
                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                    <functionalRoleCode>ADJ</functionalRoleCode>
                    <adjGroupCd>ADJ</adjGroupCd>
                    <ruleGroupCd>ADJ</ruleGroupCd>
                    <claimId/>
                    <dispatchInd>Y</dispatchInd>
                    <sourceSystemCd>STREAM</sourceSystemCd>
                    <unitAsgnmntId/>
                    <adjStrmUserId>320</adjStrmUserId>
                    <unitassignmentadjusters/>
                    <primaryInd>Y</primaryInd>
                    <firstName>asdasdasd</firstName>
                    <lastName>asdasd</lastName>
                    <userPhoneNumber>asdasd</userPhoneNumber>
                    <userEmail>asdasd@asdasd.com</userEmail>
                    <companyOrgUnitId>3000165</companyOrgUnitId>
                    <userTitle>Claims Representative</userTitle>
                    <dedIstrCd/>
                    <payStatusCd/>
                </unitassignment>
                <unitassignment>
                    <unitId>6003606</unitId>
                    <reserveAmt>4500.00</reserveAmt>
                    <reserveCovCd>csl</reserveCovCd>
                    <reserveLssTypCd>prop_dam</reserveLssTypCd>
                    <coverageCd>NA</coverageCd>
                    <insertId>dispatch</insertId>
                    <updateId>dispatch</updateId>
                    <insertTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</insertTmstmp>
                    <updateTmstmp>2013-03-27 22:33:13.000</updateTmstmp>
                    <functionalRoleCode>ADJ</functionalRoleCode>
                    <adjGroupCd>ADJ</adjGroupCd>
                    <ruleGroupCd>ADJ</ruleGroupCd>
                    <claimId/>
                    <dispatchInd>Y</dispatchInd>
                    <sourceSystemCd>STREAM</sourceSystemCd>
                    <unitAsgnmntId/>
                    <adjStrmUserId>320</adjStrmUserId>
                    <unitassignmentadjusters/>
                    <primaryInd>Y</primaryInd>
                    <firstName>asdas</firstName>
                    <lastName>asdasdasd</lastName>
                    <userPhoneNumber>asddas</userPhoneNumber>
                    <userEmail>adssa@asdasd.com</userEmail>
                    <companyOrgUnitId>3000165</companyOrgUnitId>
                    <userTitle>Claims Representative</userTitle>
                    <dedIstrCd/>
                    <payStatusCd/>
                </unitassignment>
            </unitassignments>
            <notes class="list"/>
        </claim>
    </claims>
</response>
```

Comment: What information exactly you want to show in main grid and in the detailed grid (at least `colModel` of both grids are required)? Do you though about usage of Subgrids (subgrid as Grid) instead of detailed grid? I don't see any XML schema in the response of the server. Is JSON probably better format as XML?

Comment: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935) which shows how to load and display close information using subgrids. One can implement the same using XML, the usage of JSON is just a little more easy in JavaScript and in jQuery.

Comment: Oleg, thanks for looking at this. The master grid contains the nodes at the "unit" level, the detail grid contains the nodes at the "unitvehicle" level. This detail grid is just one of the detail grids I have in place. There is another one for "unitdamages", one for "unitcoverages" and those, in turn, become master grids for their own detail grids. Because of one parent being a parent for multiple children, the subgrid scenario doesn't work for me in this case. I feed I am very close to the solution, but that selector in the xmlreader.root is not working. xmlreader.row, does it accept selector

Comment: Found solution, xmlreader filter moved from "root" level to "row" level. Also, jquery filter was wrong, was using comma instead of blank separator, because the filter condition was an "AND", not the "OR" the comma was doing. Updated main question above with the resolution.