# Jqgrid is empty, does not load json data from main grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid, subgrid

My subgrid only shows the column headers but not not load the json data from the main grid. The columns are empty. I followed the tutorial on [JQuery Grid-SubGrid for Parent-Child relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194754/jquery-grid-subgrid-for-parent-child-relation/14205263#14205263)

but it does not work.

This is my javascript code:

```
      jQuery().ready(function () {
                var grid = jQuery("#shipment_grid");
                var mainGridPrefix = "s_";
                grid.jqGrid({
                    url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getTruckShipmentJSONAction?truckId=' + <c:out value="${truckId}" />,
                    datatype: "json",
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    loadonce: true,
                    colNames: ['Lead Tracking #'],
                    colModel: [
                        {name: 'trackingNr', index: 'trackingNr', width: 100, align: 'left'}
                    ],
                    rowNum: 10,
                    height: 230,
                    width: 700,
                    idPrefix: mainGridPrefix,
                    autoheight: true,
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                    pager: jQuery('#shipment_grid_pager'),
                    sortname: 'trackingNr',
                    sortorder: "desc",
                    jsonReader: {
                        root: "records",
                        page: "page",
                        total: "total",
                        records: "rows",
                        repeatitems: false
                    },
                    viewrecords: true,
                    altRows: false,
                    gridview: true,
                    multiselect:true,
                    hidegrid: false,
                    shrinkToFit: true,
                    forceFit: true,
                    idPrefix: mainGridPrefix,
                    caption: "Shipments Overview",
                    subGrid: true,
                    beforeProcessing: function(data) { 
                        //align 'Lead Tracking #' column header  to the left
                        grid.jqGrid ('setLabel', 'trackingNr', '', {'text-align':'left'});

                        var rows = data.rows, l = rows.length, i, item, subgrids = {};
                        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                            item = rows[i];
                            if (item.shipUnitView) {
                                subgrids[item.id] = item.shipUnitView;
                            }
                        }
                        data.userdata = subgrids;

                    },              
                    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
                        var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
                            pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, rowId),
                            subgrids = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData");

                        $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
                        $subgrid.jqGrid({
                            datatype: "local",
                            data: subgrids[pureRowId],
                            colNames: ['Ship Type (Pallet / Carton)', 'Ship Unit (Pallet ID / Cone #)', 'Total Cartons'],
                            colModel: [
                                { name: "shipUnitType", index: 'shipUnitType', width: 100, align: 'center'},
                                { name: "reference", index: 'reference', width: 100, align: 'center'},
                             { name: "totalOfCartons", index: 'totalOfCartons', width: 100, align: 'center'}
                            ],
                            sortname: "shipUnitType",
                            sortorder: "desc",
                            height: "100%",
                            rowNum: 10,
                            autowidth: true,
                            autoencode: true,
                            jsonReader: { 
                                root: "records",
                                records: "rows",
                                repeatitems: false,     
                                id: "reference" },
                            gridview: true,
                            idPrefix: rowId + "_"
                        });
                    }
                }).navGrid('#shipment_grid_pager', {edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true});


            });


This is my json data from the server:

 {"page":1,
    "records":[
        {"id":2,"trackingNr":"1Z1484366620874728", 
         "shipUnitView":[{"reference":"65000943","shipUnitType":"CARTON","totalOfCartons":1},
                        {"reference":"65000942","shipUnitType":"CARTON","totalOfCartons":1}]},

        {"id":4, "trackingNr":"1Z1484366620874746"
         "shipUnitView":[{"reference":"65000940","shipUnitType":"CARTON","totalOfCartons":1},
                        {"reference":"65000939","shipUnitType":"CARTON","totalOfCartons":1}]},

       {"id":3, "trackingNr":"1Z1484366620874764"
        "shipUnitView":[{"reference":"65000938","shipUnitType":"CARTON","totalOfCartons":1},
                        {"reference":"65000937","shipUnitType":"CARTON","totalOfCartons":1}]}  
    ],
  "recordsTotal":3,"rows":10,"sidx":null,"sord":"asc","total":1,"trackingNr":null,"truckId":"174225","truckShipmentComponent":{}}
```

Comment: Please provide a working demo on jsfiddle

Comment: @Apul Gupta: I use json data and jsfiddle only supports local data

Comment: are you sure that your JSON data looks exactly like posted here? There are no comma after `"trackingNr":"1Z1484366620874746"` and `"trackingNr":"1Z1484366620874764"`. Is it cut&pased error? I recommend you to include `loadError` callback in the code to see more about the error. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there are small errors in the JSON data which you posted. It contains no commas after `"trackingNr":"1Z1484366620874746"` and `"trackingNr":"1Z1484366620874764"`. I hope that it's only cut&paste error during preparing the data for the question. In any way it would be more safe to include `loadError` callback (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935)) in case of loading errors.

Your main error seems to me are inside of `beforeProcessing` callback. The `data` parameter of the callback contains the server response. The array of items you have inside of `data.records`, but you use `var rows = data.rows, ...` instead. The line should be fixed to `var rows = data.records, ...`.

One asked you in the comment to prepare JSFiddle demo which demonstrates the problem and you had problems to prepare it because of usage `datatype: "json"`. On the other side JSFiddle do provides you possibility to implement demos in the case. One can use [Echo service](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#json). In case of jqGrid one needs just use `mtype: "POST"` and `url: "/echo/json/"`. To inform echo service which data you want to have one need just send JSON encoded data in `json` parameter. So the fill looks like

```
// the data which we want to receive back
var serverResponse = {
        "page":1,
        ...
    };

$("#gridId").jqGrid({
    url: "/echo/json/", // use JSFiddle echo service
    postData: {
        json: JSON.stringify(serverResponse) // needed for JSFiddle echo service
    },
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST",  // needed for JSFiddle echo service
    ...
});
```

The working JSFiddle demo you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ntfw57zm/. I makes some small additional optimization of your code.

I hope the example could help other people to post his questions with JSFiddle demos.

Comment: They are cut&paste errors. I actually moved "trackingNr":"1Z1484366620874746" and "trackingNr":"1Z1484366620874764" from their original positions. You are perfectly right. I actually forgot that my data is in data.records and not data.rows. Thanks for enlightening me about the echo service of jsfiddle and for making the demo. I will try it tommorro and give you feedback.

Comment: I've accepted it now. Can you please check this question for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017729/how-to-redice-the-width-of-a-jqgrid-filter-toolbar