# Store related row data?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, row

I'm looking for the best way to store per row data. I found a working way using hidden columns (hidden: true in colModel), but that option will still create DOM nodes for the hidden cells, and that seems to be a waste for me. Is there better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all one should specify **how one use jqGrid**. If one uses `datatype: "local"` then one have no need to create any hidden columns. Instead of that the input data can contains the items like

```
{ id: 123, name: "item name", price: 45.67,
    orders: [
        { total: 1543.54, data: "2015-10-02" }
        { total: 1633.71, data: "2015-10-01" }
    ] }
```

and the `orders` array will be saved in `data` array as the part of every item. In other words you can hold any number of additional properties of any type which will be saved in the local data. One can use `getLocalRow` method to get all the data. For example one can use something like `$("#grid").jqGrid("getLocalRow", "123")` to get the data associated with the row having id="123".

If one uses `datatype: "json"` and loads the data from the server then one can use another options. Free jqGrid 4.9 and higher supports `additionalProperties` parameter. So instead of creating hidden columns `prop1` and `prop2` which exists in the input data you can just use `additionalProperties: ["prop1", "prop2"]`. It informs jqGrid to read the data from input. One can use a little more sophisticated for on `additionalProperties` items to read more complex data and to associate the to the row. The main advantage of the usage `additionalProperties`: the specified properties are accessible in custom formatters and the properties will be saved locally if one use `loadonce: true`.

If somebody used TreeGrid then one could see many hidden columns (`level`, `parent`, `isLeaf`, `expanded`, `loaded`, `icon`) which are saved additionally in the local data. The hidden columns was not used internally since many versions of jqGrid. Starting with version 4.9 free jqGrid don't creates the unneeded columns and makes DOM of the page shorter. Free jqGrid uses `additionalProperties` in the case (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/additionalProperties-option-makes-unneeded-hidden-columns-in-local-scenario)).

In one can't currently migrate to free jqGrid then one can use another workaround. One can use `userdata` to save additional information associated with the grid. One can either include `userdata` directly in the server response with all required information or one can use `beforeProcessing` callback to parse input data and to fill additional `userdata` **before** the input data will be parsed by jqGrid. I recommend to read [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935) for the corresponding code example. The main idea is in building `userdata` as map by rowid. The items of the map should contains the additional properties:

```
userdata: {
    /* properties of userdata could be the rowids */
    123: {
        /* the data could contains the object with additional properties */
        orders: [
            { total: 1543.54, data: "2015-10-02" }
            { total: 1633.71, data: "2015-10-01" }
        ]
    }
}
```

It allows to use

```
var addProp = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData");
```

and to access additional properties using `addProp[rowid].orders`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I load data from server using json datatype. I couldn't find any docs about the 'additionalProperties' option. And anyway, I use jqgrid 4.6.0 at the moment. So the userdata option seems the best for me. Thanks!

Comment: @user3599803: You are welcome! `additionalProperties` option exist starting with version 4.9 of free jqGrid. I included the reference on [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/additionalProperties-option-makes-unneeded-hidden-columns-in-local-scenario) and have descried the option in my answer. If you use old version of jqGrid (4.6.0) then it has no such option and you have to use `userData` for example.

Comment: I searched in the docs here and didnt find - http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs

Comment: @user3599803: I wrote you that `additionalProperties` option exist in [**free jqGrid**](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid and it not exist in 4.6.0 version described on http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs.

Comment: hmm, I actually didn't notice the license change, I used to know jqGrid (trirand site) was MIT licensed. I think I should switch to this free jqGrid now. Does all the previous features of jqGrid still work with the free version?

Comment: @user3599803: I tried to hold maximal compatibility with jqGrid 4.7 , 4.6 and other old version. Some small compatibility issues are described in [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README48.md#compatibility-with-jqgrid-470). It's mostly the problem of changing *internal* methods which could be probably used in your code. I suggest everybody to try to change URLs to jqGrid to URLs from CDNs described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). One will see whether you should expect some compatibility problems or not.