# Sub grid from same data as main grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I load my main grid data via json (from mysql).

My grid consists of orders. Each order contains a number of items (order lines).

I would like to query all order lines in one query at load. These order lines should be grouped by order id.

This is what I want:
Main grid: only show one row per id (with totals of the values in sub rows)
Sub grid: a '+' on each main row. When I click it, the sub grid appears, showing each sub row

Is this possible with jqGrid? Or do I *have* to do extra queries for the sub grids?

Best regards
Ole

Comment: How many orders you need to display? Is the number is about 100 orders, about 1000, 10000 or more? Which web browser (and which version) is the main web browser which you need to support. If the number of orders is not so large one can do the most work on the client side and returns from the server all orders at once.

Comment: About 100 orders. each with about 1-10 order lines. My main browser is Chrome (latest). I would like to do it client-side: load all data and distribute data in main and sub grids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to display about 100 orders especially if you use modern web browser like Chrome with quick JavaScript you can do all work *on the client side*. The server should just provide all data sorted by id. You can load all the date at once using `loadonce: true`.

I suggest you to read carefully [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935) which is based on the ideas from the previous answers ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10178440/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13241406/315935)). I think that it provide the solution of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look into it. For now I'll go with the two  different queries. This isn't working for me either!!! See my other post here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435025/jqgrid-subgrid-data-not-loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
url:'example.php',
datatype: 'xml',
mtype: 'GET',
colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
colModel :[ 
  {name:'invid', index:'invid', width:55}, 
  {name:'invdate', index:'invdate', width:90}, 
  {name:'amount', index:'amount', width:80, align:'right'}, 
  {name:'tax', index:'tax', width:80, align:'right'}, 
  {name:'total', index:'total', width:80, align:'right'}, 
  {name:'note', index:'note', width:150, sortable:false} 
],
pager: '#pager',
rowNum:10,
rowList:[10,20,30],
sortname: 'invid',
sortorder: 'desc',
viewrecords: true,
caption: 'My first grid',
subGrid: true,
subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
// we pass two parameters
// subgrid_id is a id of the div tag created within a table
// the row_id is the id of the row
// If we want to pass additional parameters to the url we can use
// the method getRowData(row_id) - which returns associative array in type name-value
// here we can easy construct the following
   var subgrid_table_id;
   subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
   jQuery("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table>");
   jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
      url:"subgrid.php?q=2&id="+row_id,
      datatype: "xml",
      colNames: ['No','Item','Qty','Unit','Total'],
      colModel: [
        {name:"num",index:"num",width:80,key:true},
        {name:"item",index:"item",width:130},
        {name:"qty",index:"qty",width:80,align:"right"},
        {name:"unit",index:"unit",width:80,align:"right"},           
        {name:"total",index:"total",width:100,align:"right",sortable:false}
      ],
      height: '100%',
      rowNum:20,
      sortname: 'num',
      sortorder: "asc"
   });
    }
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Reference: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid

Comment: This uses 2 different db-queries, right? ('example.php' and 'subgrid.php')