# JSON format for subgrid

Tags: json, jqgrid

hello can any one tell me the json format for local data containing the subgrid values.
i used following format but subgrid data is not loading into the subgrid table.

```
var data=[{"Left_ssr_id":CaGM33098,"Mismatches":"6","Gaps":"1","AlignLen":"1119","Identity":"99.37","right_ssr_start":17308507,"Qstart":"33","query":"AB-Contig743","subject":"Ca7","Send":"17305359","Score":"2113","Evalue":"0.0","Left_ssr_end":17293825,"right_ssr_end":17308542,"right_ssr_id":CaGM33099 ,"Sstart":"17304241","Qend":"1150","Left_ssr_start":17293811,subgrid:[{"Right_ssr_start":17308507,"Right_ssr_end":17308542},{"Right_ssr_start":17308506,"Right_ssr_end":17308543}]}]
```

code used to upload the data . The Grid is getting the data but subgrid showing only the header and the blank rows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#blastform").submit(function(){
     jQuery.ajax({
         data: $(this).serialize(),
         url: this.action,
         type: this.method,
     dataType: "json",
         error: function() {
             $(thistarget).html("<span class='error'>Failed to submit form!</span>");
         },
         success: function(res) {
    var data=res;
$("#datatable").jqGrid({
    datatype:"local",
    data:data,
    colNames:['QueryID','SubjectID', . . . 'Right_nearest_distance'],
    colModel:[ {name:'query',index:'query', width:55},
        {name:'subject',index:'subject', width:80},
        .,
        .,
        {name:'right_near_dist',index:'right_near_dist', width:50, sortable:false}, ],
    rowNum:100,
    rowList:[100,200,500],
    pager: $('#pager2'),
    sortname: 'QueryID',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'desc',
    loadonce: true,
    altRows: true,
    pgbuttons: true,
    subGrid : true,
    subGridUrl: 'local',
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id)
    {
    var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
    subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
    pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
    $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
    jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['ssr_start','ssr_end'],
    colModel: [ {name:"Right_ssr_start",index:"Right_ssr_start",width:80,key:true},
            {name:"Right_ssr_end",index:"Right_ssr_end",width:130},
             ], 
    rowNum:20,
    pager: pager_id,
    sortname: 'ssr_start',
    sortorder: "asc",
    height: '100%' });
    jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{edit:false,add:false,del:false}) },
    caption: 'Blast Results'
    });
    $("#datatable").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2', {position: 'right'});
    jQuery("#datatable").jqGrid('navGrid','#blastresults',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});

         }
     })
     return false;
     }
);
);
```

Comment: It's important to know *how* you provide the data for jqGrid. Do you use `datatype: "local"` together with `data: data`? How columns of grid are defined in `colModel`? Which field of data unique and so can be used as the rowid? If you posted the response from the server with the data (if you use `datatype: "json"`) then you should use other jqGrid options. So you should append your question with more information.

Comment: @Oleg: i provide the script which i used to provide the data for jqgrid.

Comment: It's wrong to make separate ajax call and to use `datatype: "local", data: data`. You will have many disadvantages. jqGrid provide `datatype: "json"` type for the case. One can use additional options like `jsonReader` and `jsonmap` to inform jqGrid how to get information about grid data from the server response. Your main question was about subgrid, but the code don't shows how you fill the subgrid. I will write short answer with reference to another old question which could probably help you.

Comment: @oleg: Actually my script didnt worked so i implemented the Ajax call then i used datatype: "local". now jqgrid is working fine without error. Thank you i am awaiting for your reponse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the localReader settings

see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#array_data

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to make separate ajax call and to use `datatype: "local", data: data`. You will have many disadvantages. jqGrid provide `datatype: "json"` type for the case. One can use additional options like `jsonReader` and `jsonmap` to inform jqGrid how to get information about grid data from the server response.

The value for `var data` which you posted provide wrong data. You use variables `CaGM33098` and `CaGM33099` which are undefined. If you used cut&pased from the server response, then you generate wrong JSON response on the server. Moreover it's strange that `subgrid` if the item from `data` array isn't enclosed in `"`. Probably the server returns from `this.action` (??? what is `this` here???) the following data

```
[
    {
        "Left_ssr_id": "CaGM33098",
        "Mismatches": "6",
        "Gaps": "1",
        "AlignLen": "1119",
        "Identity": "99.37",
        "right_ssr_start": 17308507,
        "Qstart": "33",
        "query": "AB-Contig743",
        "subject": "Ca7",
        "Send": "17305359",
        "Score": "2113",
        "Evalue": "0.0",
        "Left_ssr_end": 17293825,
        "right_ssr_end": 17308542,
        "right_ssr_id": "CaGM33099",
        "Sstart": "17304241",
        "Qend": "1150",
        "Left_ssr_start": 17293811,
        "subgrid": [
            {
                "Right_ssr_start": 17308507,
                "Right_ssr_end": 17308542
            },
            {
                "Right_ssr_start": 17308506,
                "Right_ssr_end": 17308543
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

[The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13241406/315935) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13779589/315935) shows how one can implement displaying nested data as subgrid. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935) shows how to use [userdata](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#user_data) to load nested data *directly from the server*. I recommend you to use the last approach.